# call activity from service

Tags: java, android

It has been asked a few times before but the solution provided couldn't solve my problem. I am working on the app which has several classes: mainactivity, SMS, and MService. service has a timer. I am trying to call SMS to send a text message every time timer is over. Can please someone help me ....
Thanks for consideration...

```
public class MService extends Service {

    private Handler HandleIt = new Handler();
    private final int INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    boolean timeout = false;


    public interface SmsService
    {
        void SmsServiceSenter();
    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }





    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {



        @Override
        public void run() {
            HandleIt.post(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), TextonScreen(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  // Intent smsintent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SMS.class);
                  // startService(smsintent);
               }
            });
        }


   }

    private String TextonScreen()
    {
        timeout = true;
        return "it is running";

    }
    boolean isTimeout()
    {
        return timeout;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Display the Toast Message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Execute an action after period time
        //comes from the TimeDisplayTimerTask class
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, INTERVAL);


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Display the Toast Message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stop it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}

public class SMS extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        message();;


    }

    boolean issent = false;
    String text = "I am here";
    String num = "2085578209";
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();




    public void message()
    {
       // if(Timeout.isTimeout()) {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, text, null, null);
            issent = true;
      //  }
    }
    boolean isSent()
    {
    return issent;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you want start activity? on service launch?

Comment: Service cannot directly communicate with the activity so you have to register a broadcast and call the broadcast when you send the sms from the service.When the broadcast onReceive() is called  start the acitvity.

Comment: you can write broadcast receiver on your main activity and call this broadcast from your service onReceive() method call new activity

Comment: I want to launch activity When the interval is done. About every 30 seconds I make a toast it is "It is running" I want to launch activity at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really simple.
After you create your Intent variable, before starting activity add a flag to it like below

```
Intent launch = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(launch);
```

With this above code you can call activity from service

Comment: Above provided code works only once, when I launch an app. I want it to happen repeatedly, over and over again  Like " private String TextonScreen()" ..

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Your code helped me a lot thank you for help. I changed a code a bit and placed it in the run function. only problem is it only sends Sms when the screen is on. if it is off it doens't work..